# My preview is showing blank in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

1. I have clean and rebuild project
2. I have invalidated and restarted
3. I have changed `Theme.AppCompact.Light.NoActionBar`
   To `Base.Theme.AppCompact.Light.NoActionBar`
4. I have added **alpha1** to `android.support`

Is there any solution/s that are different from those that are above please?

**Please Note:** It runs on an Android device, it's the preview screen in Android Studio IDE.

Comment: Have you tried turning your computer off and on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your code? Maybe there are some mistakes.

Try to comment some code lines and check which line of code gives you problems.

Finally if you're sure your code is right, try to restart Android Studio and if that doesn't work either, try to create a temporary testing project and Copy-And-Paste your code inside that project.

If the problem is in your code, you will see the problem also in the new project. Else if your code is right and the problem will be Android Studio, the second solution will resolve your problems (maybe your first project was corrupted).

Comment: I don't think there's error in the code because when I run the app it works perfectly fine with my phone, it's just the preview that's blank.I wanted to put in the picture but Stackoverflow did not allow me to do that

Comment: Ok, try to reboot the PC and Android Studio or try to create a new project and import the files in this one. I solved many times my problems in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing API, Pixel, and zoom in/out in the Android preview panel, it could be a bug of the preview.